# How to add Azure AD sign-in to old Webform solution? Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, webforms, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, asp.net-4.5

After looking at many code-sites and tryed out code sampels and ideas, I can't find a working way for my situation: I just want my old webforms app to get Azure AD sign in possibilities.
The old webapp is still selling very well so plan is to extend it.

Situation:

I have an classic Webforms solution on Framework 4.5.

Authentication mode="Forms".

I have a simple and custom membership provider.

Simple custom user table with scrambled passwords.

No MVC app, no controllers. Just plain old Global.asax, webcontrols and so.

Many users are in a tenant on a Azure AD. Or Office365 users. I want them to log on to my app.

ACS and AzMan are gone.

### Now, in what way can I add Azure AD sign in feature?

Code tips, code examples?

I have seen texts and code samples for MVC apps and newer types.
Seen how to register my app in Azure AD, create a client secret, note the App ID, tenant ID and so. But no luck getting a working logon.

Some links read many times:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp
and
Section "Quickstart Guides. Build a simple app to sign-in with user’s or app’s identity and call Microsoft Graph API in a few steps" on https://portal.azure.com/

Comment: Hi @lava, Is any solution you got on this? I am also facing same issue and want to add startup class without OWIN module for classic asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could follow below steps to implement azure AD login in asp.net web form.

1.Add the code in Startup.cs.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
         app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
         app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
         new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
         {
               ClientId = "7d68201b-xxxxxx",
               Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9ab4e-xxxxxx"
         });
}
```

2.Force a user to sign in by requesting an authentication challenge in your controller:

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
}
```

3.Add button click for login.

```
<div>
     <asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="Login_Click" />
</div>
```

4.Add Redirect Url of your project url and click Implicit grant of Id token in app registration app in azure ad.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. My webforms app does not have a Startup.cs file and the Configuration(IAppBuilder app) functions. It's old webform :-) your code looks like the MVC examples from MS. Is there a way I have to mix something here?

Comment: You can create a class called Startup.cs.

Comment: The code I provided to you is webform which I test in my site and can work well with AAD.

Comment: I create a login button click event to trigger the login.

Comment: my solution does not have any owin package or libs like Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb. Startup.cs is never called. Is owin a must have to get this type of login to work? so even without MVC I must have all the owin stuff included? in my webform app

Comment: Looks like Owin is one option and a good one. Other way was WIF but more work. If owin then there are some packages to install. ok, it's the way it is. 
Now I am unsure about this web.config authentication setting now. It must me "Forms" as this old solution is dependant on it, but this owin require "None". How to have both? Anyone?

Comment: I have not test before, but I set authentication as forms and the owin also work well. You can have a try.

Comment: maybe setting this to "forms" in a brand new solution equals setting it to "none" because "forms" is not understood anymore. that mode may be abandoned. just a guess

Comment: Maybe you can have a try. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Looks like Forms authentication is setup in Startup.cs file now (VS2019) using "app" extension "add"-functions. So all Form auth in web.config is removed. Set to "None" and removed (<module <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>).

I did try to run an old forms auth solution (without owin. initially from 2010) together with code on new owin based OpenID towards Azure AD. It did NOT work. Both auth systems were messing up authentication for each other. They both grab http pipeline and edit it. Messy.

Comment: Looks like a big point here is that my Forms auth is based on libs from 2010, dotnet 4.0 and so. No Owin anywhere. All webform auth solutions made the last few years have been Owin based. Big diff probably.

Answer (score -1):

Have check authenticated user by using following code when we come back after

I am not able to comment but I think this is the way how we can check authenticated user when we come back and by login by Azure username/Password.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
{
   string Email = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Comment: The question isn't about retrieval of identity information for an already logged in user, but rather how to actually implement Azure AD authentication.